# Remove duplicate (Unnecessary) Project Reference in .NET Solution

Tags: .net, msbuild

I googled this but found nothing at all, which is why I am asking.

I have a .NET solution which contains about 20 projects, and I am using a layered architecture.

Suppose project `A` will reference Project `B`. 
Project `B` will reference projects `C`, `D`, `E` and `F.` 
.
Projects `C`, `D`, `E` and `F` all reference the `G` project. 
and `G` project references `H` project.

Now I have a path from project `A` to project `H` and I can use its types.
What I wanted to do to avoid unnecessary `<ProjectReference>` tags.

For example, there is no need to reference the project `H` directly from `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F` projects, because all of them have reference to it indirectly by referencing `G` project.

MS-build does not appear to produce any warning, about those duplicated (unnecessary)
`<ProjectReference>`, Is there an extension to VisualStudio that could project this warning and tell me to remove those references that I really should not reference directly? or anything else?

Comment: What about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/remove-unused-references?view=vs-2022?

Comment: No, it is not what I am looking for, according to the documentation from the page you referenced it said `The Remove Unused References dialog will open displaying references that have no usage in source code`. I am not asking about removing unused libraries, I am asking about removing references that the project already has (and uses)

Comment: @Progman, I also created a minimal solution consisting of 3 projects and I tested that, It did not work, the message I received was `No unused references were found.`

Comment: What I am trying to do is to leave only one path from one project to another, and not have multiple paths between projects in the dependency graph. @Progman

Comment: There is a difference in behavior between .NET Framework and .NET (aka .NET Core) for [`ProjectReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#projectreference). You are expecting project references to be transitive and that will be true for .NET projects but false for .NET Framework projects. There is a [`DisableTransitiveProjectReferences`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#disabletransitiveprojectreferences) property.) Seems reasonable to make a feature request for an optional warning.

Comment: The SDK-style project behavior is mostly in MSBuild files that are auto-imported. Running /preprocess and searching for the `DisableTransitiveProjectReferences` property may give some insight into how to custom implement the warning.